Does the Vanishing Integral over Expanding Intervals Imply Convergence?
I'm trying to solve this problem about the convergence of improper integrals and could really use some help. The statement in question is as follows:
If $f(x)$ is continuous on $[a, \infty)$ and $\lim_{x\to \infty }\int_{x}^{2x} f(t)\,dt=0$, does it necessarily follow that the integral $\int_{a}^{\infty }f(x)\,dx$ converges?
Initially, I tried using the Cauchy criterion for convergence, and i also noticed that $\int_{a}^{\infty }f(x)\,dx=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\int_{na}^{2na}f(x)\,dx$, and $\lim_{n\longrightarrow \infty }\int_{na}^{2na}f(x)\,dx =0$, but couldn't show that the sum converged and hit a dead end.
Is there a more suitable approach to prove the statement? Or could someone provide a counterexample that disproves it? Thank you in advance for your assistance

The statement is not true. Consider
$$f(x) = \frac{2\pi\cos\left(2\pi\log_2(x)\right)}{x\log (2)}$$
which integrates to
$$\int_x^{2x}f(t)dt = \sin\left(2\pi\log_2(t)\right)\Biggr|_x^{2x} = \sin\left(2\pi\log_2(x) + 2\pi\right) - \sin\left(2\pi\log_2(x)\right) = 0$$
but clearly the integral $\int_a^\infty f(t)dt$ does not converge for any fixed $a>0$.

how did u get to that integral in the 1st place

@LÜHECCHEgon the function itself is messy because I was thinking of a nice antiderivative instead.
